# Serve static content from cookieless domain

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, laravel-5, dns, web-deployment

Trying to fix this problem with my app I ran into another. I have a Laravel app which I deployed to a live domain. Doing some testing I found out that I need to serve static content from a cookieless domain and that's what I did.
I created a subdomain (static.exameple.com) which points to the public_html folder. Then I set up a new CNAME in my DNS and changed all my links to point to this new domain to load the css,js etc files.
I also added this lines in my htaccess:

```
# Use Mod_deflate to compress static files


SetOutputFilter DEFLATE  



# Speed up caching
FileETag MTime Size

# Expires
ExpiresActive On  
ExpiresDefault "access plus 366 days"

# Future Expires Headers

Header set Expires "Sat, 27 Dec 2014 23:59:59 GMT"
```

Now, this works fine and it loads my files. The problem is with my routes. Some of them point to the correct things (for e.g domain.com/home works fine) but some point to the static domain. (for e.g when I want to open a model it tries to open it from the static.domain.com) What is the problem here? I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: I believe you might not be able to use asset or mix function but will have to hard code the static domain urls into your blade files for your static content.

Comment: Or you could add an env var pointing to your static domain, 
copy the asset or mix function (depending on what you use) and modify it to read from your env variable, use the new functions instead of asset/mix